# Are there any function in python to click on the links to open and extract the email?

Tags: python, email, web-scraping

I'm looking for a tool that extracts emails from web pages, but with the particularity that the emails are not directly on the page but on the page there is a list of icons with links, and each one links to a popup that contains the emails in practice manually you have to click on each single icon to see the related email. The emails are not obscured and there is no prohibition, they are freely available, indeed they are there just to be consulted, is there any tool to do this?
Otherwise I have seen several scripts in python but without this functionality, is there any function in python to click on the links to open and extract the email? If you have examples that would be great!

Comment: Have you tried just going straight to where the email is and selecting that by ID or Class Name? Instead of dealing with button clicks and other things of that nature if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand what you're trying to say, but I've understood that you want to retrieve emails from a webpage. If this is what you're trying to do, then my following answer covers that, hope it helps-

Web scraping emails in Python is fairly simple. There are 2 parts you want to figure out- the first step is how to download the web page, and the second step is how you want to extract the emails from that data.

In Python, there is a neat library called [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which allows you to download websites (that's only the tip of the iceberg, but that's all what is needed for this answer). The requests module can download web pages very easily, like so:

```py
from requests import get

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
html_data = get(url=url).text
```

After that, you now have your HTML data inside the `html_data` variable. Now on to the next step- parsing for emails. Another neat tool we have in Python is a module called [re (also known as regex)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Regex (or Regular Expressions) is a "language" which lets Python find specific strings within a bigger string. In our case, we can use a regex statement to find emails in the HTML data. You can do this like so:

```py
from re import findall

# Regex statement taken from https://emailregex.com/
print(findall(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", html_data))
```

The code above will take all the emails from the HTML data and print them to the screen. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help, I try to explain better, normally these scripts or tools extract the emails that are visible by browsing the page, while they do not extract those that are on the page but accessible by the visitor by clicking on an element of the page, for example example a flag, and a window opens where the email is displayed. In practice you have a page with a list of contacts that to be viewed by the visitor must be clicked and opened one by one, I hope it is clearer, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, with inspect browser element these emails are not seen

Comment: @tecno78 if they are not seen with inspect element, then they are not in the HTML code at all (they will not show up if you request them in the way that my answer has specified. In your case, they are probably requested with an API call. You will need to inspect what request is being sent by your browser when you click to get the email, then replicate it with the `requests` module.

Comment: hello, can you link me to any resource that explains this so that I can document me?
alternatively, couldn't you create a sort of bot, which simulates clicking on objects of the same type on the page (which "contain" the emails)?